# JQuery Map UI and opening info window from links

Tags: jquery, google-maps, dictionary

As mentioned, I am using the JQuery Map UI plugin and am having a hard time trying to figure out how I can have a  list of locations, that once clicked, will open the info window in the map.

Here is my working code to pull in map markers and output a list of locations outside the map.

```
$.getJSON( 'data.php', function(data) {
$.each( data.markers, function(i, m) {
    var temp = m.services.split(',');
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng),
        'bounds': true,
        'services':temp
    }).click(function() {
       $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': m.address }, this);
    });
   //list of locations that once click, will open the map info window
    $('ul.list').append('<li><a href="#" >' + m.address + '</a></li>');
});
});
```

As of right now, the above will only allow the actual marker inside the map open the info window. Any help/direction on having the UL list of items be clickable and also open teh info window would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I possible way(there may be others):

Store the `google.maps.Marker`-instance as a property of the `<li>`-element, so you may access it on a click on this element and trigger a click on the marker:

```
$.each( data.markers, function(i, m) {
    var temp = m.services.split(',');

    var marker=//<--create a local variable
          $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
            'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng),
            'bounds': true,
            'services':temp
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': m.address }, this);
        })[0];//<--note the [0]

   //list of locations that once click, will open the map info window
    $('<li><a href="#" >' + m.address + '</a></li>')
      .data('marker',marker)
       .appendTo('ul.list')
        .click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                google.maps.event.trigger($(this).data('marker'),'click');
              });
});
```